# Conditional sum in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am using Pandas to process some financial data in csv form.I have a table as follows:

```
ID Amount Type 
001 33 CR
001 40 DB
001 30 CR
002 99 CR
```

I want to add it based on ID and Type both. Answer should resemble something like this:

```
ID CR DB CR_FREQ DB_FREQ
001 63 40 2 1
002 99 0 1 0
```

This means I need to add the amounts and split them accordingly. Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try via `pivot_table()`:

```
out=df.pivot_table('Amount','ID','Type',fill_value=0,aggfunc=['sum','count'])
```

Then:

```
out=(out.swaplevel(axis=1)
        .rename(columns=lambda x:'_FREQ' if x=='count' else '',level=1)
        .rename_axis(columns=[None,None])
        .reset_index())
```

Finally:

```
out.columns=out.columns.map(''.join)
```

output of `out`:

```
    ID  CR  DB  CR_FREQ     DB_FREQ
0   1   63  40  2           1
1   2   99  0   1           0
```

Comment: This answer works, although I totally missed something in the question(Sorry for that). I have edited it to reflect the actual question

Comment: @sinha-shaurya updated answer....kindly have a look ***:)***